# Is there a way to call onload event listeners in GWT + elemental2?

Tags: java, gwt

The following code is not triggering while loading the page
(elemental2 + GWT):

```
element.addEventListener("load", new EventListener() {
        
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event evt) {
        DomGlobal.alert("yes i from onload event...");
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this meant as a custom event, or are you trying to trigger the handler that normally responds to something like an `img` `load` event etc?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I got to load the data in select box when the page loading or after loading using elemental2 library classes (but not from com.google.gwt.user.client)

Comment: Without you specifying more details in your question, it is possible that the event was on the wrong element, or that the element wasn't attached to the dom (which gwt protects against since that can leak memory in older browsers).